# Windows cannot find 'winword.exe'

Tags: ms-word

On one computer host I can launch winword.exe e.g. via Delphi ShellExecute or just typing winword.exe in command line of TotalCommander app. I don't think winword.exe is on the PATH.

On another computer, that has Office installed, I can't launch winword.exe via same launch methods mentioned above. I get message "Windows cannot find 'winword.exe'. Make sure you types the name correctly, and then try again.

Does this related to some registry settings maybe?

I have noted that

Registry settings as per: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe

are present on one environment where winword.exe works and not present on the other environment .. Maybe I can set these up ..  Maybe I should be asking:    Why are these registry settings not setup ?

Comment: I found an article here that might help me    https://www.actualinstaller.com/help/winword.html

Comment: Registry settings as per:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Winword.exe

Present on one environment and not on another ..

Comment: Allan F, it's on my computer as that registry setting.  If you find that setting missing, you could do a search of the hard drives for it.

Comment: Strangely, I don't seem to have winword.exe on my machine .. (I thought I saw it last week) ..  Using "Everything" tool to search ..    But MS Word still works ..  Smoke and mirrors ..

Comment: I don't remember windows ever having Microsoft Word on every computer because in the early days, you had to buy it or it came as a bonus package to your computer.  It was mainly a buy it product.